# Como faço para a imagem ficar centralizada na table

Tags: html, table

```
                      <html>
              <head>
                <title> Teste inicial </title>
              </head>
               <body>
                  <table style= "width:480" "height:480" border="1">
               <tr>
               <th colspan="2" > Nome Principal </th>
               </tr>
               <tr> 
<td> Lacuna 1</td>
<td> Lacuna 2 </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td height="80" > Lacuna 3</td>
  <td height="80" > Lacuna 4 </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <table border ="5">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><img src="instagram-1581266_960_720.jpg " style="width:180px;">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque na `<td>` o alinhamento centralizado:

```
<td align="center">
   <img src="uma_imagem.jpg" />
</td>
```

Comment: Começo por dizer que não fui eu que dei o -1 e acho que é exagerado que o tenham feito uma vez que funciona. Mas sugiro que coloque uma nota a dizer que apesar de ser possível de fazer como tem na resposta, que é recomendado que seja feito em CSS

Comment: Tranquilo. Eu já penso que é melhor usar as funções nativas do elemento em vez de usar CSS.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do DvD está correta mas recomendo você seguir os padrões da W3C para HTML5.2, porque em algum momento este formato usado para alinhar não será suportado pelos navegadores e você terá que refazer seu site de novo, já que este formato já está depreciado desde o HTML 5.0, assim como todos os atributos de significado apenas visual, porque existe as CSS para isso e a questão da imagem também está errada porque segundo a W3C toda imagem deve ter um texto alternativo alt e com isso o código certo seria assim:

```
<td style="text-align:center;">
   <img src="minhaImagem.jpg" alt="Está é uma imagem de alguma coisa"/>
</td>
```